# Converting Jpanel to image using OOP

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

i have been extensively researching on stackoverflow and other platforms to find out the solution to my problem.I do understand that this is a duplicate question and I totally understand how to convert JPanel to an image based on Java tutorial and other existing post on stackoverflow . However, i'm trying to do it in OOP as i don't want to chunk all my codes within the same method. The result i keep getting is blank and it doesn't show my component in PNG file that ive exported.

File 2, imageOutput.java

```
public class imageOutput {

    public JPanel panel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton btn = new JButton("Click");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Exporting image example");

        // -----Add to panel ---
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(btn);
        panel.setSize(200,200);
        btn.addActionListener(new saveImageListener());
        return panel;
    }

    public void frame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = panel();
        // --- Add to frame ---
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}

class saveImageListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        JPanel panel = new imageOutput().panel();
        System.out.println("Step 1.. ");
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        System.out.println("Step 2.. ");
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        panel.printAll(g);
        g.dispose();
        try {

            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("Paint2.jpg"));
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("Paint2.png"));
            System.out.println("save");
        } catch (IOException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Main class, main.java

```
public class main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
             new imageOutput().frame();
            }

}
```

When i run the program, it results blank as mentioned above. ive been trying to figure out whats the cause of it for the past week and i have not come out with any solution. Has anyone encounter this problem and able to solve ?

**BUT**  when i do it this way , it's perfectly fine. However, it's not oop for me.

```
public void frame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton btn = new JButton("Click");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Exporting image example");

        //-----Add to panel ---
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(btn);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
                panel.printAll(g);
                g.dispose();
                try {

                    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("Paint2.jpg"));
                    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("Paint2.png"));
                    System.out.println("save");
                } catch (IOException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        //--- Add to frame ---
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //btn.addActionListener(new saveImageListener());
    }
```

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a compounding one.

When you call `panel()` on an instance of `imageOutput`, it's create another instance of the `JPanel`, in of itself, this isn't a bad thing, but you need to remember that this new instance has nothing to do with what's on the screen.

In the example you've provided, this means that no layout pass has been done on the component, so all the components are at there default position/size (which is `0x0x0x0`), so nothing gets rendered

If you're going to continue creating a new instance of the panel each time you call `panel()`, then you're going to have to force a layout pass, maybe something like...

```
JPanel panel = new imageOutput().panel();
panel.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
panel.doLayout();
```

Now, personally, I'd avoid `setSize` and passing it "magic" numbers and instead use the components `preferredSize`, but that's me

Comment: Finally , Thank you soooooooo much . youre the best. . In regards using setsize, ill use setprefferedSize instead. once again. Thank you :)